# SWIFT: How to filter local data store in the app

Tags: swift, filter

I have an array of data stored in the app.For example:

```
struct ClassInfo {
  var id: String
  var name: String
  var city: String

 static func fetchStudent() -> [ClassInfo] {
  var studentInfo = [ClassInfo]()
  let s1 = ClassInfo(id: .... name:..., city: CA)
  let s2 = ClassInfo(id: .... name:..., city: ZD)
  let s3 = ClassInfo(id: .... name:..., city: NY)
  studentInfo.append(s1)
  studentInfo.append(s2)
  studentInfo.append(s3)
 }
```

In the viewController I have:

```
self.students = ClassInfo.fetchStudent()
```

My question is: How do I fetch students that has "CA" under city?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to use filter function:

```
self.students = ClassInfo.fetchStudent()
let caStudents = self.students.filter {$0.city == CA}
```